# Entitlements.plist not created properly

Tags: iphone, plist, distribution, adhoc, entitlements

reading the doc from apple I need to create an ad-hoc distribution app, and to do so  I need the entitlements.plist.
when i create a new entitlement, the value "get-task-allow" is not present, so I added by hand.. is right??
at the end the Entitlements.plist is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    </array>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Have the same problem with latest install (xcode_3.2.4_and_ios_sdk_4.1.dmg).

Comment: I have the same problem. Haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try, in XCode, to go "new file" and in the wizard select "code signing". Select the "Entitlements" file type.

Just name it "Entitlements.plist". 
Make sure the task-allow is not checked for adhoc distrobution.

This is all you need to do, no need to "roll your own" :)

(Xcode 3.2.2)

UPDATE:

Since **Xcode 4.2** the `Entitlements.plist` was removed from the "new file" menu. You now find it under: `Project's Targets > Summary` at the bottom of the page.

Comment: thanks ricky, I do exactly this, but the key get-task-allow doesn't appear, appear a application-identifier and keychain-acces-groups...
so I need to remove them and only leave get-task-allow (false).. 
I dont'know how is to true, i've added the key, selected boolean and leave unchecked, but the code is true...

Comment: Sounds really weird. I just tried a few settings combination to see if I could make a new entitlements.plist look like that, I can't.

Do you have a developer key installed in the keychain? did you add something to the info.plist file or did any sort of extra setup stuff in the projects settings?

Comment: yes, I have a developer key installed in the keychain.. i'm private developer.. and sounds strange also for me... I try to change manually the .plist with the only get-task-allow key to false and no other....

thanks Ricky

Comment: You are welcome, but I am out of ideas.. If it is any help here is the content of a working entitlements.plist file. You can edit yours in a texteditor and paste this in:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>get-task-allow</key>
 <false/>
</dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 5):

You can do so. Also you can select your Entitlements.plist in XCode and select in Main Menu: View / Property List Type / iPhone Entitlements plist. Then your key can be selected from dropdown list and will be called "Can be debugged" (as quite as I remember - it should be the only key avaliable in this list)

Comment: This is the answer you're looking for. "Can be debugged" is the 'friendly' key for `get-task-allow` (right click, Show Raw Keys/Values confirms this).

Answer (score 3):

In XCode 4.2, the Entitlements file has been moved. It's now part of the project root's "Targets" section, at the bottom of the list of the "Summary" items.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I manually created a new row "get-task-allow", changed type to boolean and actually had to have it set to true to get the device token.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, with enterprise provisioning.
After lots of googling I found [this](https://gitorious.org/lpmt/lpmt/source/5a8fe04d1d386228f979e2c98c3c464bc9fcccf4:Entitlements.plist#L17). Extracted the ipa, copy the Entitlements.plist to the Payload folder and codesigned with the method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195564/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-install-on-ios-8-1-3). didn't do anything else, it started installing properly.