# App Rejected for failing to launch? ...and others

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My game was just rejected from the AppStore for the following two reasons...

> We found that your app failed to launch on iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1,
>   on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> We encountered the issue when selecting the application on the Home
>   screen - the app displayed a launch image then quit unexpectedly

And

> Your app did not run at iPhone resolution and/or 2x iPhone 3GS resolution when reviewed on iPad.

Both of these confuse me, I currently do not have Lion installed so cannot test in 5.1 but, it works just fine in 5.0.1 and below.

Also, I have been testing on only my iPad, have no iphone to test on, but the game and graphics run just fine on the iPad. Though! I only have graphic files labeled @2x.png, and none with out it. Could that be the problem here?

If anyone has any advice that would be awesome, I responded to apple's rejection, but i bet it takes a while for them to get back to you, and i'd really like to move this along. Thanks!

**Updated

My `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Is as follows

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];

    mainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc] init];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenu];
    self.navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    [[GCHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"missingWordsAdded"] intValue] != 1) {
        [self forceAddWords];
    }

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"EnableSoundEffects"]){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"EnableSoundEffects"];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

GCHelper sets up GameCenter. thanks!

Comment: You should really install the latest iOS SDK before submitting an app.

Comment: I know that seems really obvious, but I was sorta thinking I'm only .1 version behind, Im not using any new features, and I was thinking that if apple was still allowing xcode 4.2 to be downloaded, why would'nt they let Apps be uploaded with it?

Comment: .. what code do you have in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function in your app delegate?

Comment: @MaxBallo So for my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: see updated question

Comment: @JamesDunay What is your MainMenu Init function doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a few suggestions:

1. Do a reset on your simulator, launch your program and see if it works
2. Uninstall your app from iPad, run it from Xcode and see if it works
3. Ask a friend to test an ad-hoc copy, or attach to your Xcode and run debug copy
4. Depending on your implementation, you should do some blind check on your startup code (`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or singleton instances). Especially those area that involves GCD, @synchronize, access on `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. And things like default preference initializing and database creation are likely to produce this kind of problem.

Regarding the review process, my log indicates that Apple staff at Cupertino uses an iPad 2 with WiFi connection to run your app. They are not toying with you if they say they can't run your app.

Comment: Ive done 1-3 tested on 10+ devices, reset the simulator to factory settings, and tested on an iPad. All still working as always. So maybe its something in my implementation?  I'm only creating a few string in the NSUserDefaults, and making a couple dictionary entries to the master dictionary, but really nothing huge. What is blind checking?

Comment: @JamesDunay, maybe ask another person to review the code for you? Blind check is reading your code without executing it. Sometimes it's easier to spot the problem this way. If possible, code review by a second person is preferred. Focus on the parts that execute during startup.

Comment: Ahhh gotacha. This might be a really dumb question. however apple suggested that it might be a missing entitlements.plist file.  I'm using xcode 4.2, is this something that I must have? because it still is working fine on all tested devices, but does apple require this for submission?

Comment: @JamesDunay have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021569/entitlements-plist-not-created-properly ? I pretty much followed these two tutorials: http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/31/how-to-deal-with-iphone-device-provisioning-without-stabbing-your-eyes-out/ and http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices when deploying. I recall if there's a problem with code signing, Application Loader should be able to detect it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I may change a couple of things and re-submit

Answer (score 1):

1) "app failed to launch" for different configurations of phone and iOS is a big issue to reproduce because you may not have all the phones with different iOS versions at hand. You can try https://testflightapp.com/ for example, and can come to know your app performance with different configurations.

Answer (score 0):

my app is also rejected for same reason. here u have first check the internet connectivity where it will needed than u have do your code.

to check  internate connectivity u can use reachability classes.

Comment: can you explain a little more? I have to check for internet connection where? Maybe before I check for gamecenter?

Comment: u have to check it before u required intern ate connection like if u r using Facebook connect than u have to check before user click on Facebook  connect button