# i am not able to install Self Signing/ Resigning IPA file on iOS 8.1.3, but it is still working in lower versions of iOS 8.1.3

Tags: ios, ios8-extension

i am not able to install Self Signing/ Resigning IPA file on iOS 8.1.3, but it is still working in lower versions of iOS 8.1.3
it is showing as installing on device but it is not intalling.

Comment: Maybe your developer program membership has expired?

Comment: @Vatsal Manot No but it is still working on lower versions of iOS 8.1.3

Comment: Verified developer program membership. It has not expired.

Comment: See answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195564/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-install-on-ios-8-1-3