# iOS 8.1.3 - Enterprise distribution not working

Tags: ios

we have a few apps that we install on our devices using an Enterprise distribution profile. To install an app, we use the usual `itms-services` link:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=...
```

We use the same link to install updates to the apps.

Ever since this latest iOS update (8.1.3) something strange is happening with the link. On some devices, and only for one or two of the apps, the link does absolutely nothing. It pops up the dialog with Install or Cancel, but when the user presses Install nothing happens. The app's icon doesn't get the loading overlay, nothing. To make matters worse, all the apps on all the devices have been installed the exact same way, yet it only happens to some apps on some devices. An app that installs fine on one device will have this problem on another.

On one of the devices that are having this problem, I even tried uninstalling the app, and then running the link again, but still nothing happens. In fact, now I can't install the app at all on that device, since nothing happens when the link is clicked!

Things I've tried:

- Restarting the device
- Removing all profiles from the device

Does anyone know what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: When the app download fails, the device logs the error. Did you see through the device logs?

Comment: Yes I went through the logs, there's nothing there... The device doesn't even attempt to download the app, which is the problem...

Comment: I believe [this question and subsequent answer][1] may be helpful to you :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195564/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-install-on-ios-8-1-3

Comment: @Mark thanks for the info, but it's not exactly the problem I'm having... In my case, the app doesn't even try to download, so I don't get the "Could not be installed" message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a hacky way around this bug. If I change the bundle ID in the manifest file to something different, such as adding "-ios8fix" or something to the end, then it'll install. It doesn't look as nice, since during the installation there's a second app icon on the screen. But once the installation is finished, the second icon disappears.

One benefit of doing it this way though, is that if the installation fails the user can still use the old version of the app, since there'll temporarily be 2 icons, one for the old version, and one for the update...