# Crashes after update (Transferring Ownership of iOS App)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

I'm responsible for an iOS App development and we were using an individual apple account on this App. Now the company decided to move to a Corporate Account.

I read everything in [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) and then executed the whole process.

This App does not use Keychain, so I didn't see any problem in moving forward with the process. It would not affect the current users on the update.

**THE PROBLEM IS:**

*Now when I update from previous version (using old account) to the latest version (using new Account) the app crashes immediately (only shows the Launch Screen and crashes).*

Additional Info:

1. The generated *Application-Identifier* has changed from ***team_id1.com.myapp*** to ***team_id2.com.myapp*** as expected.
2. We're using Fastlane on the build/deploy process
3. We're using Crashlytcis to Crash Report (which is not triggering any report on
   those crashes).
4. All Certificates (Push, Development, Distribution) were recreated on the New Account.
5. Installing the new version from scratch works just fine.
6. I'm downloading the update from Internal Testflight
   Tests.

EDIT: I'm suspecting that it may not be a crash. It might not open the app at all and it's aborting the launch before it can reaches `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: I suggest looking at the device's console log for any messages generated during the update.  (Xcode->Window->Devices)

Comment: @PhillipMills, no lucky on the Device's console log. Only a few other crashes that are not related to this issue. When I try to debug the latest version with the old one already installed on the device I get this message error on Xcode: **"This application's application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade be allowed."**.

Comment: It seems to me that my issue is related with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31710576/661216) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195564/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-install-on-ios-8-1-3/28235443#28235443), but I'm not completely sure yet.

Comment: After a lot of research and talking with Apple's support, it turns out that it does not crash in the Production mode. But it does crash when App is installed via Crashlytics Beta or TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in Production the update process goes through as expected.

I got in touch with Apple support and they taught me that the crash was expected in the early stages of development and distribution (Alpha and Beta via TestFlight). They also said that I wouldn't have any problem during distribution in Production.

Based on this information I did a new build and submitted it for approval in iTunes Connect. After it has been approved I published it  and until now I did not get any crash because of that update (changing the TeamId).